# WebAPI and OData OrderBy

Tags: asp.net-web-api, sql-order-by, odata

I have a data model consisting of two entities

```
public class product 
{
     public int ID {get;set;}
     public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class category
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<product> products {get;set;}
}
```

What I need to do: starting from category how can I sort by product name?

I've tried something like this:

`api/categories?$orderby=?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you query the `Categories`, you cannot order by `Product` name, simply because you can only order `Categories` by `Category` properties.

If you want to query the products of Category 1, for instance, you can search for `api/categories(1)/products?$orderby=Name`.